# Electric shock from circuit with load vs no load

Tags: electricity

If a person came into contact with a 110V 20A ungrounded conductor with a load on it, say a refrigerator for example, would they receive a greater shock as the same circuit with no load on it given the same conditions in both situations ?

Answer (score 1):

They will receive the same shock, for all intents and purposes.

In theory, the result will be slightly lessened.  We can model the system as a voltage source with wires that have some resistance going from the source to the person, and then onward to the refrigerator.  It's trivial to show that the person and refrigerator, in parallel, have a lower resistance than the person would have on their own.  Since the wires and the person-sans-fridge or the wires and the person-with-fridge effectively form a voltage divider, we can see that the person-with-fridge will have a lower fraction of the total voltage because it makes up a smaller portion of the total resistance.  Lower voltage equals lesser shock.

That being said, realistically speaking, the resistances involved will *not* be enough to make this activity safe.  We generally make sure our power-main wires have very low resistance, so in both cases the person will feel nearly all of the 110V.  The difference of having a load on the line may not even be measurable compared to other sources of noise on the line.  The end result will be the same: crispy critter.

The one exception might be a brownout.  If the load on the line is *so* great that it can exceed the generator's capacities, the load may be able to reduce the voltage on the line measurably.  A refrigerator cannot do this, but an aluminum smelter coming online without warning the power company first might do the trick.  In this case, the load may reduce the 110V to something smaller, like 80V.  That being said, 80V is still enough to get you killed.

Comment: Suppose the ungrounded conductor has been cut and a person completes the circuit by touching both ends of the ungrounded conductor ,line and load sides, and completes the connection to the fridge? Would there be more current ,and more shock, to the person?

Comment: Generally speaking, it would be less, because you have a series resistor rather than a parallel one.  The actual effect would be *very* dependent on the particular load, so the voltage the person experienced would be very unpredictable.  Some motors behave like a short when they first turn on, which would cause the person to experience nearly the full 110V.  other loads may not behave that way.

Comment: Thanks that's puzzled me for some time. I guess that's why I lived...